# Which tool or regex can replace text,only retain middle contents of this text by one step?

Tags: regex

I have these text:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resUrl}/static/public/js/jquery.json-2.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resUrl}/static/merchant/js/shopCat/shopCat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resUrl}/static/merchant/messages/messageShopCat_${locale}.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${resUrl}/static/merchant/js/components/sortabletreetable_${locale}.js"></script>
```

I want a tool/regex,which only one step,can replace all "`<script type="text/javascript" src="${resUrl}/` and  `"></script>`"

that's to say, only retain src attribute value(not Contain `${resUrl}/`)

this time,I use **notepad2**, I need two steps:

first, I replace `<script type="text/javascript" src="${resUrl}/` whith space

second,I replace `"></script>` whith space too

I want a tool/regex,which just only one step,can be faster to help me with my work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about _wanting_ a tool/regex.

Comment: Why Java tag is here?

Comment: do you want to do this in Java ?? the content is from javascript.

Comment: Sorry,have remove java tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below regex expression in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="\$\{resUrl\}/|"></script>
```

Here `|` is used as `OR` in regex expression and `\` is used to escape the character that is part of regex itself.

[image]

Comment: cool thanks,this code useful for me